# Time Machine uid problem

Tags: time-machine, backup, permission

Here is the problem I'm having with retrieving files from my Time Machine:

```
$ pwd
/Volumes/LaCie/Backups.backupdb/H2/Latest/H2/Users
$ id -u dbae
501
$ id -u Rona
502
$ ls -ldn dbae
drwxr-xr-x@ 106 502  502  3604 15 Jan 08:57 dbae}
```

Here is how this happened. My MacBookPro broke down. Workshop told me 10 days to repair, 10 days of inaction that I cannot afford. `No problem' I thought. I will work on our MacAir, plug in the Time Machine Backup disk, and retrieve any particular files that I need. (There's not enough space available on the MacAir to think of doing more than retrieving one file at a time, as needed. And I have to be careful not to mess up the existing files on the MacAir.)

However, as you can see from the above code, the uids are different on the two Macs. The consequence is that the permissions on the TM backup disk will not allow me to read the files I need. I'm VERY reluctant to change permissions on the TM files, as I think I could easily loose the backup completely.

Can anyone think of something simple for me to do? I don't mind a bit of extra hassle every time I need a file, though it would be best if I could write a script to retrieve individual files or directories from the TM disk. I do know the passwords of all the users on the MacAir and I have admin privileges.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though Apple predicted this situation and made provision for it.
I found the answer at http://pondini.org/TM/17.html
David